# c# Gridview - Bind selected columns from datareader

Tags: c#, gridview, bind

I have a sql statemente but I don't want to display all info in the gridview (c# webforms). How to bind specific columns at runtime on gridview?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd edit columns in Visual Studio Designer so I would get exact columns I want.

It depends how do you fetch data into DataGrid. If you use SqlDataSource I would recommend make a close up on `Selecting` event. In other case (SqlDataReader) I'd make binding while reading. Or you can also use Linq to Entity to get values what you want, just like this:

```
var name = from names in context.data_table
           select names;
gridview.datasource = name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the columns for the DataGridView yourself. Example:

```
DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();

dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;

dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "FieldA";
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "FieldA";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "FieldB";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "FieldB";

bindingSource1.DataSource = GetDataTable();
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to **Data Bind** your grid after you set a Data Source like shown above. Best of luck!

```
Entities entities = ObjectContextManager.GetCurrentContext<AdHocReportingEntities>();
var users = from e in entities.Users  
    where e.State == userState'
    orderby e.Name   
    select new { e.Name, e.State};  
Grid.DataSource = users; 
Grid.DataBind();`
```